# Suitable verb form in a sentence

Tags: verbs

I have a question as follows:

> Fill in the blanks using the most suitable form from the list given below
>
> "All visitors will be asked to register at the front desk prior to _____ the government building."
>
> 1. enter
> 2. entering
> 3. be entered
> 4. entered

I think 1. or 2. can be the correct answer, but can't decide which one is the best.
Could anyone tell me which one is the most suitable and why?

Answer (score 1):

All visitors will be asked to register at the front desk prior to **entering** the government building."

Gerunds show the actions as concepts.
Ex: Running is neccessary.

Here 'entering' has become a concept which is to be done after registration.

Comment: Please get a feel for the standard of questions expected on ELU, a site aimed at linguists. This, a question most 12-year-old native speakers would be expected to know the answer to, should be close-voted rather than answered. Left unanswered, if one has not the C-V privilege. // An explanation of the answer would include the fact that  'prior to' takes a noun phrase or an ing-word or ing-clause.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used English Language Learners Stack Exchange rather than this site. And thank you for your additional explanation.